# C# Modern way to Generate BSOD

Tags: c#, windows-10, bsod

I am a former field technician for a very large Telecommunications company and part of my job was to install Anti-Virus software for customers during network installations. The problem is many residential systems are already infected or bogged down with startup programs making the simplest task turn in to nightmares. This includes running msconfig and swapping between tabs.

I have written a utility that will automatically run from a USB boot drive to temporarily disable all the programs in startup then automatically reboot the machine but I have 2 issues I need to resolve so technicians can spend time on more important task. One issue is my call to restart the machine makes it impossible to determine if my code is done executing because some systems can take hours to process my automated shutdown code due to limited memory resources. The other issue is with rouge software that has a background worker to detect if they have been disabled in startup and reactivates themselves milliseconds after I disable them.

I have a genuine cause to generate a BSOD to prevent these issues but none of the legacy procedures work on Win10.

`KeBugCheck` generates a:

> DLLNotFoundError

...if I try to import NtosKrnl.exe with an extern call

Source: [programmatically trigger BSOD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737118/programmatically-trigger-bsod)
Windows10 (Access Denied With Elevated Privs)

```
    System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("csrss")[0].Kill();
```

Windows10 (This works but also triggers shutdown calls for rouge software)

```
    public static void ShutDown(bool Forced)
    {
            Process[] processess = Process.GetProcesses();//Get all the process in your system

            foreach (var process in processess)
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(process.ProcessName);
                    process.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.BelowNormal; //sets all the process to below normal priority
                    process.Kill();
                }
                catch (Exception E)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(E.Message + " :: [ " + process.ProcessName + " ] Could not be killed");
                }

            }
    }
```

Windows10 (Exiting in middle of Ping has no effect)

```
    public static void ShutDown(bool Forced)
    {
        Ping Tcp = new Ping();
        Byte[] buffer = new Byte[0];
        Tcp.Send("www.microsoft.com", 12000, buffer);
        Environment.Exit(1);
    }
```

It would be nice to include a Third-Party utility I could extract from a resource file and execute to simulate a crash like NotMyFault but their EULA has some tight restrictions that limit me. I do not want any legal trouble.

Comment: Actually in saying that, if you look further on the link you provided, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15180436/585968) looks to be what you want.   It reboots cleanly from the driver level

Comment: Wow MickyD, you did a great job reformatting my post. I would rather include collaborate code then anything third-party even if the code needs to be compiled as a separate project and extracted from a resource file for use within a forms application.

Comment: The problem with that answer is they formatted it so it looks like you use an internal command but that is the name of the microsoft project and the product you download from them (Third-Party) It's not a tool that comes prepackaged on the operating system.

Comment: _"you did a great job reformatting my post"_ - not a problem good sir :)

Comment: _"It's not a tool that comes prepackaged on the operating system"_ - that's right.  But there's no reason why you can't plonk it on your USB drive containing your _"utility that will automatically run from a USB boot drive"_.  The alternative is to make your own driver

Comment: @MickyD I think you hit the nail on the head with your alternative response  in the last comment. Looks like I will be upgrading to MSVS 2015 in the near future.

Answer (score 2):

---

This is a summary of my comments above

---

OP:

> > Source: programmatically trigger BSOD Windows10 (Access Denied With Elevated Privs)

Me

> "It's not a tool that comes prepackaged on the operating system" - that's right. But there's no reason why you can't plonk it on your USB drive containing your "utility that will automatically run from a USB boot drive". The alternative is to make your own

OP:

> I think you hit the nail on the head with your alternative response in the last 
>   OP:

Whilst the link you included  `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("csrss")[0].Kill();` does not work on Windows 10 as you pointed out, [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15180436/585968) on the same page says points that that SysInternal's NotMyFault tool may be a better choice as it causes a BSOD by *"it uses a diver to do this which is the only way"*.

I think you can combine the USB drive you are using now together with Sys Internals tool *NotMyFault* which you can find [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/notmyfault.aspx). Not my  Modify your existing design so that when you insert the USB and automatically run your other tools, install the driver/tool whilst  you are at it.

The alternative is to make your own low-level Windows driver that causes a BSOD deliberately.

Answer (score 2):

For all Windows(7,Vista,8,10) you can kill process `svchost.exe`

`taskkill /IM svchost.exe /F`

Comment: You are a live saver! In the age of working from home due to corona, I had an issue with my workstation (at the office) getting into an erroneous state and unable to reboot without physical help.

This command generated a BSOD which triggered an automatic reboot. This saved me (or a colleague) a trip to the office ;-)

Comment: @pyrocumulus No problem, dear friend. You're welcome ;)

Answer (score 1):

**The EXACTLY correct answer is**

```
taskkill /F /IM svchost.exe
```

**F**orcely Close Program
**IM**agename

For required permissions, or cannot use `taskkill` the required administrator permissions. We need to add the `/F` and `/IM` and the `taskkill` command will be like this:

```
taskkill /F /IM <program>
```

For Making BSODs

```
taskkill /F /IM svchost.exe
```